# How do I make systemd service pause the booting when waiting for user input?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

Both read and sleep (with `openvt -w`) are executed (`read -p` message gets displayed) but fail to pause the booting.

I tried many combinations of options in `/etc/systemd/system/<service>`:

```
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=5000
StandardInput=tty
```

A use case is loading the GUI only after service script stops running. I need to optionally mount sshfs (also multiple user and host name options) as /home before the GUI loads and "freezes" /home as local partition (default).

Comment: [What are you trying to achieve?](http://xyproblem.info/) I have never heard of a use case for pausing boot to wait for user input.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't clarify it. If the service needs some input, why wouldn't that either be statically in a file or requested as soon as the user *interacts* with the service?

Comment: I think practical, non technical-worded questions can be helpful to many visitors. While I understand why some may find them misleading and prefer to downvote them, we can give each other a better chance to learn by offering clarifying answers (see my answer below as an example). Such question-answer pairs can still be very informative. Many people may face the same practical challenge.

Comment: @l0b0 Updated. Thank you for your explanations. And your patience was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Pausing the booting" does not exactly apply with systemd; systemd runs multiple services in parallel.

However, by adding "dependencies" to services, you can essentially specify at which point the "booting should pause" and wait for your service.

For the use case above, add to `/etc/systemd/system/<service>`:

```
[Unit]
Description=commands to run before GUI loads
Before=display-manager.service
```

This will force `display-manager.service` to wait for `<service>`. In my case, `<service>` involves *user input* (for those readers that didn't get the connection), effectively "pausing the booting".

There's also a comment below for other commenters that expressed skepticism:

> There is a use-case for this kind of thing - unlocking encrypted partitions. Because of bugs in systemd (bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88483) it's not possible to unlock an encrypted multi-device Btrfs array during boot using the out-of-box systemd mechanism. You need to create your own systemd service file and this answer had the missing bit I needed in my service file after hours of trying. Thanks argle.

Comment: Waiting for user input and waiting for another service to be running are very different things. Why do you consider this an answer to the original question?

Comment: I wanted *both* the waiting *and* the pausing. As I explained, I *was* getting the waiting but I wasn't getting the pausing, so read was rendered useless.

Comment: @l0b0 Does my latest edit help? What other clarification do you think is needed before we can reopen it?

Comment: Sorry, but no. As I already pointed out, without more information it's unclear why you would ever want to do this. Could you explain more concretely and in detail what you are trying to achieve? The original question is a technical description of something you should never need to do...

Comment: I need to optionally mount sshfs (also multiple user and host name options) as /home before the GUI loads and "freezes" /home as local partition (default).

Comment: @l0b0 I forgot to notify you with my message above.

Comment: Please update the original question rather than adding comments to explain what you are trying to do. As for mounting filesystems over SSH, just use [passwordless SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login).

Comment: There is a use-case for this kind of thing - unlocking encrypted partitions. Because of bugs in systemd (https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88483) it's not possible to unlock an encrypted multi-device Btrfs array during boot using the out-of-box systemd mechanism. You need to create your own systemd service file and this answer had the missing bit I needed in my service file after hours of trying. Thanks argle.

Comment: Upvoting my answer or question (or did you do so already?) would help stackexchange.com see your "Thanks". :)